# Angular Velocity definition about point

Tags: reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, angular-velocity

Is Angular Velocity always defined about a point about which the body is rotating? Except for Instantaneous Center of Rotation and COM of body, how do you define angular velocity of a rigid body about any other point in space about which the body does not seem to rotate? I have the same doubt for angular acceleration too.

Is Angular velocity (and Angular acceleration) same about any point in space?

Answer (score 0):

Angular momentum is defined about a point or an axis.

Angular velocity normally means the same thing but be careful.

Rotation is a turning process.  While it is usually described about an axis it is an absolute quantity and rate of rotation does not need to be described about a particular axis.

A rotating body such as Earth has angular momentum around the Sun as well as its own angular momentum about its polar axis.

Comment: Consider a disk of radius  R rotating around its center with some angular velocity. what would be the angular velocity of a disk about a point which is at a distance D from center?

Comment: Angular velocity as you are using it in the comment above is the rate of rotation.  The disk can have the same rate of rotation about any point, but will have a different angular momentum.  Angular momentum is calculated by multiplying the rate of rotation by the body's moment of inertia about the axis of rotation.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem for how the moment of inertia changes when you use an axis that does not go through the centre of gravity.